# How to Build Translation System

Tags: system, translation

I want build translate system to translate text from english to arabic.

what kind of language should I use?

also what steps should I follow to build this system?

Answer (score -1):

You should before think to an algorithm for translation, after you can use whatever language you like denpend on where you will use the application (web, phone, terminal,..), i think translation systems works with graph implementation.

Comment: can you give example for algorithm people uses in this cases

Comment: can you give example for algorithm people uses in this cases

Comment: https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT it's an open source translator based on neural networks